# Elastic Search Terms aggregation is not working properly based on terms filter list

Tags: json, elasticsearch

Following is my query:

```
{
  "size" : 0,
  "query" : {
    "bool" : {
      "must" : {
        "match_all" : { }
      },
      "filter" : {
        "bool" : {
          "must" : [ {
            "terms" : {
              "unblindMemberId" : [ "first", "erw", "810182628017", "ewrew", "swer", "rew", "wer", "ewr", "ewr", "r", "r", "dsf", "810218592401", "sd", "s", "last" ]
            }
          }, {
            "bool" : {
              "must" : {
                "exists" : {
                  "field" : "udf7_lab"
                }
              }
            }
          } ]
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "aggregations" : {
    "members" : {
      "terms" : {
        "field" : "unblindMemberId"
      },
      "aggregations" : {
        "top_risk" : {
          "top_hits" : {
            "size" : 1,
            "_source" : {
              "includes" : [ "udf7_lab" ],
              "excludes" : [ "" ]
            },
            "sort" : [ {
              "svc_service_date" : {
                "order" : "desc"
              }
            } ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

In the above query terms aggregation is not working as it is supposed to. 
Data for the first element ie first is not being pulled.But,when last element of unblindMemberId is removed ie. last. Data of first is being pulled.
also, when only first and last element is added
 ie. `unblindMemberId:["first","last"]`
records is being pulled for both the ids.

When query was executed without aggregations terms filter is working properly since all the unblindMemberIds were being pulled including first and the last ids.

Few other records in the list beside first and last is also not being pulled.

In my view,

```
"aggregations" : {
    "members" : {
      "terms" : {
        "field" : "unblindMemberId"
      }
}
```

this particular aggregation is unable to pull the desired record. Im unable to determine the cause, since the basic functionality of terms aggregations is not working. any help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that in the terms aggregation. I didn't set size=0 since by default only 10 data is pulled when size is not set. Hence i solved by adding size as:

```
"terms": {
        "field": "unblindMemberId",
        "size":0
      }
```